# Display Each Column sum on footer Yajra Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

The following screenshot shows the list of database results by enabling server-side processing. It shows the column total computed by using the Yajra DataTables.
[image]

**HTML Code for DataTables with Column Total**

To display the footer using html builder, pass true as 2nd argument on `$builder->table([], true)` api.

```
{!! $dataTable->table([], true) !!}
```

[image]

**script**
update th values

```
@push('scripts')
    {!! $dataTable->scripts() !!}
    <script>
        var hours = JSON.parse("{{json_encode($hours)}}");
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("tfoot tr>th:nth-child(2)").text("Total")
            for (let i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
                $('tfoot tr>th:nth-child('+ (i+3) +')').text(hours[i])
            }
        })
    </script>
@endpush
```

**Report Datatable File**

In Query function we are getting reports record from database and use query result in dataTable function make column according to our requirement and finally set values to getColumns function.

```
public function dataTable($query)
{
    $reports = ($query['data']);
    return datatables()->make($reports)
        ->addColumn('name', function ($reports) {
            return isset($reports['user_name']) ? $reports['user_name'] : null;
        })
        ->addColumn('monday', function ($reports) {
            return isset($reports['Mon']) ? ($reports['Mon'])  : '-';
        })
        ->addColumn('tuesday', function ($reports) {
            return isset($reports['Tue']) ? $reports['Tue']  : '-';
        })
        ->addColumn('wednesday', function ($reports) {
            return isset($reports['Wed']) ? $reports['Wed'] : '-';
        })
        ->addColumn('thursday', function ($reports) {
            return isset($reports['Thu']) ? $reports['Thu'] : '-';
        })
        ->addColumn('friday', function ($reports) {
            return isset($reports['Fri']) ? $reports['Fri'] : '-';
        })
        ->addColumn('total', function ($reports) {
            return (isset($reports['Mon']) ? $reports['Mon'] : 0) + 
                   (isset($reports['Tue']) ? $reports['Tue'] : 0) +
                   (isset($reports['Wed']) ? $reports['Wed'] : 0) +
                   (isset($reports['Thu']) ? $reports['Thu'] : 0) +
                   (isset($reports['Fri']) ? $reports['Fri'] : 0);
        })
        ->addIndexColumn();
}
public function query(Lot $model)
{       
    $data = Reports.....;
    return compact('data');
}
public function html()
{
    return $this->builder()
                ->setTableId('userrequestdatatable-table')
                ->columns($this->getColumns())
                ->minifiedAjax()
                ->dom('Bfrtip')
                ->orderBy(1)
                ->buttons(
                    Button::make('export'),
                );
}
protected function getColumns()
{
    return [
        '#' => [
            'data' => 'DT_RowIndex',
            'name' => 'DT_RowIndex',
             'orderable' => false,
             'searchable' => false
        ],
        'user name'=> [
            'data' => 'name',
            'name' => 'name',
        ],
        'monday'=> [
            'data' => 'monday',
            'name' => 'monday',
        ],
        'tuesday'=> [
            'data' => 'tuesday',
            'name' => 'tuesday',
        ],
        'wednesday'=> [
            'data' => 'wednesday',
            'name' => 'wednesday',
        ],
        'thursday'=> [
            'data' => 'thursday',
            'name' => 'thursday',
        ],
        'friday'=> [
            'data' => 'friday',
            'name' => 'friday',
        ],
        'total'=> [
            'data' => 'total',
            'name' => 'total',
        ]
    ];
}
```